# Why are vectors in physics assumed to be represented as column vectors?

Tags: vectors

I was reading over the definition of a dot product, and the stated equivalency was that $a\cdot b = a^Tb$. I always assumed that vectors were represented as row vectors, not as column vectors, but it seems the opposite is generally accepted. Is there a particular reason for this?

Comment: Isn't [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Algebraic_definition) clear?

Comment: well if you apply a matrix on a vector you get a vector. If you prefer (convention) to write the matrix on the left of the vector, than it has to be a column vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why to use one notation over the other is a matter of convention really. Given a vector space $V$ over $\mathbb{R}$ for example, it is convention that when we introduce a basis $\{e_i\}$ of $V$ we represent

$$v = \sum v^i e_i$$

as either the element $(v^1,\dots, v^n)$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ or the column vector

$$[v]=\begin{bmatrix}v^1\\ \vdots\\v^n\end{bmatrix}$$

sitting on $M_{n\times 1}(\mathbb{R})$ the space of matrices of $n$ lines and one column.

When the second option is chosen it is then also *a convention* that given the dual space $V^\ast$ (the vector space of all linear functions $f : V\to \mathbb{R})$ and the dual basis $\{\varepsilon^i\}$ defined by requring $\varepsilon^i(e_j)=\delta^i_j$ one represents the covector $\omega\in V^\ast$ with

$$\omega = \sum \omega_i \varepsilon^i$$

by the row vector

$$[\omega]=\begin{bmatrix} \omega_1 & \cdots & \omega_n\end{bmatrix}$$

living on $M_{1\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ so that the action of $\omega$ on $v$ coincides with the action of the row vector on the column vector.

Of course you could represent vectors on $M_{1\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ and covectors on $M_{n\times 1}(\mathbb{R})$. But then if $[v]\in M_{1\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ and $[\omega]\in M_{n\times 1}(\mathbb{R})$ you would have

$$\omega(v)=[\omega]^T [v].$$

While with the usual choice you have just

$$\omega(v)=[\omega][v].$$

As for the dot product, the thing is that when there is one inner product, every vector yields a covector. So if $a,b\in V$ the covector associated to $a$ is $\omega_a$ given by

$$\omega_a(v) = a\cdot v.$$

In particular $a\cdot b = \omega_a(b)$. Now if $\{e_i\}$ is an orthonormal basis that meaning $e_i\cdot e_j = \delta_{ij}$ we have that $[\omega_a]=[a]^T$ which yields your formula

$$a\cdot b = [a]^T [b].$$